# How to send mail from a Domain/Service in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail/) installed, I want to send mails from a Service/Domain class method  , I was doing like this

```
   class TrainingService {
      def mailService
      public def sendMail() {
        mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            to "abc@xyz.com"
            subject "Hello,"
            body 'How are you?'

          }
}
```

I got error "Cannot invoke method sendMail() on null object", How to resolve this

Comment: Where are you calling sendMail?  Do you call it like this: `trainingService.sendMail()`?  Is your TrainingService defined: `def trainingService` where you call it?

Comment: I am calling trainingService.sendMail() from a controller

Answer (score 1):

I am missing the "from" attribute and if you're using multipart email, you should also fill in additional parts of the email, snippet from my code:

```
mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            from '"Some account" <someaccount@email.com>'
            to 'anotheremail@somedomain.com'
            bcc emailAddresses.toArray()
            subject dto.title
            body emailPart1
            html g.render(
                    template: 'emailNotification',
                    model: [ name: dto.name ]
            )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your SMTP server. You need these entries in your config file for mail to work. Do you have these ?

```
grails {
    mail {
                    host = "hostname"
                    pop_port = 25
                    username = "username"
                    password = "password"
                    type = "pop3"

                }
}
```

you can find more information about the configuration [here](http://grails.org/plugin/mail/)

Comment: Yes, I have configured the, I could able to send mails from controllers not from domain/service classes

Comment: Try grails clean and run the app  and see if you getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was passing variables called 'from' and 'to' into the method that was using sendMail. Try renaming the sendMail method and making sure that you don't have any conflicting variable names.